# How to create a custom command in VSCode to modify my text for translation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, scripting, localization, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-tasks

Having to do localization throughout the entire project.
I have to change every text in the project from

```
<p> Home </p>
```

to

```
 <p> {t("Home")} </p>
```

Is there a way to bind a shortcut, such that on the selection of `Home` text and pressing the key binding with converting it to the required format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+i l",  // or other combo
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "{t(\"$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\")}"
  }
}
```